# generate a pivot table out of mysql data with php

Tags: mysql, pivot

I am having problems to figure out, how to make a pivot table with php/mysql.

There is no Code now, its mor to understand how it works.

Lets say i have a Table with packages

```
Table packages
pack_ID   pack_Name
1            ABC
2            XYZ
3            DEF
```

and so on

Then a Table with Items which are part of the packages

```
Table items
item_ID    item_Name
1            red item
2            blue item
3            green item
4            black item
```

And a Table to mix them

```
Table item-pack
pack_ID   item_ID
1           2
1           4
2           1
2           3
3           2
3           4
3           3
3           1
```

And the result should be a pivot table

```
item/ pack
             ABC     XYZ     DEF
red Item              x       x
blue Item     x               x
green Item            x       x
black Item    x               x
```

First i would QUery the Packages with:

```
SELECT p.pack_ID, p.pack_Name FROM packages
```

Which should give me and array with the packages.
Then i would run a for each or while and query the items like this

```
SELECT i.item_ID, i.item_Name FROM item-pack ip
JOIN item i ON i.item_ID = ip.item_ID
WHERE ip.pack_ID = $ValueFromThe QUery
```

But how the heck do i retun the result as a pivot?

is this so dificult with php?

Thy for any help.

Comment: You should pivot in the query, not the PHP.

Comment: looks so dam complicated with this Concats in mysql^^ Tahts for now way to high for me

Comment: It's not going to be less complicated in PHP.